# Is there a console command to unlock all quests in Fallout 3?

Tags: fallout-3

I know there are console commands to spawn entities like Liberty Prime into the game, as well as giving the player certain items and perks, like the Power Armour Training. But is there a command to unlock all the quests in Fallout 3, or do you have to keep exploring the wasteland in hopes of finding the quests?

I have searched all over Google and have only found Spawn Commands as well as Item Commands

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I know is how to start/reset a quest.
`startquest <quest_id>` - to start any specified quest.
`resetquest <quest_id>` - to reset any specified quest.

If you have done everything that is needed to complete the quest but it says that you still need to do something, it's probably a glitch.

All you need to do is type this in your console:
`completeallobjectives/completequest` - it will finish all quests (note: this only applies to quests of which you have completed all objectives but that say you still need to do something.)

Comment: I believe ```caqs```, short for 'complete all quest stages' does a similar thing, but I don't remember exactly.

Answer (score 1):

i never tried before but it seems you can

from the fallout wikia consola command list "quest section"

> saq - start all quests

[console commands list (check the quest section)](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Gamebryo_console_commands)

also you can activate and set progress one by one, by using quest base id

[quests list (click one of them and you can find stage codes for setting progress)](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_3_quests)

Comment: This command skips to the end of the game. It doesnt show any other quests other than the ones I already have

Comment: then what happens? are you unable to play after that? if you dont have game of the year edition you cant play after completing. i got it im gonna check it. i used to open quests one by one its works in certain situations maybe all quest command only works in certain situation. and i wonder there is a thing about that, normally some quest are failing after getting some other quests, so maybe it isnt reaally posible to activate all quests.

Comment: That explains it. I dont have the game of the year edition. I guess I will have to get each quest 1 by 1 then :)

Comment: i tried now with game of the year, doesnt works in that either. game completes and doesnt show any map marker/quesst marker :D but i remember one by one opening works in certain conditions, maybe someone with better fallout knowledge can make activate all in once but i dont sure. i suggest you try the mods maybe you can find a quest activation mod

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround:

Save the game.
Then open the inbuilt game console and enter the command 
caqs

This will completes all stages of all quests. By doing so, get out of console menu.
The quests that just were finisehd are mentioned. Write them down before the text vanishes.
IF you have done that, relaod your saved savegame and take a look at the quests name in the internet and how to trigger them.
If you have missed a quest by writing it down, just relaod the save game and to the steps above again.